# fast search specific column for specific keywords with stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, search, stored-procedures, search-engine

I wrote a stored procedure that gets:

- "SearchKeys" - keys to search separated by ',' "key1,key2"
- "ToSearch" - Tables to search in separated by ',' with colums after ':' separated by '.' "table1:column1.column2,table2:column1.column2"

At the end procedure returns table with name of table and row id were the key was found.

here is the code:

```
--Search keys in tables
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Search_All]
(
    @SearchKeys nvarchar(50), --Keys to search separated by ','
    @ToSearch varchar(200) --Tables to search in separated by ',' with colums after ':' separated by '.'
)
AS
BEGIN
    --create table with found values
    CREATE TABLE #Results (TargetId int, DBName varchar(20))

    --Split SearchKeys to Keys
    WHILE LEN(@SearchKeys) > 0
     BEGIN
        DECLARE @Key NVARCHAR(25)
        IF CHARINDEX(',',@SearchKeys) > 0
            SET  @Key = SUBSTRING(@SearchKeys,0,CHARINDEX(',',@SearchKeys))
        ELSE
            BEGIN
            SET  @Key = @SearchKeys
            SET @SearchKeys = ''
        END
        --Split ToSearch to Tables
        WHILE LEN(@ToSearch) > 0
         BEGIN
            DECLARE @TableAndColums VARCHAR(200)
            IF CHARINDEX(',',@ToSearch) > 0
                SET  @TableAndColums = SUBSTRING(@ToSearch,0,CHARINDEX(',',@ToSearch))
            ELSE
                BEGIN
                SET  @TableAndColums = @ToSearch
                SET @ToSearch = ''
                END
            SET @ToSearch = REPLACE(@ToSearch,@TableAndColums + ',' , '')
            --Split @TableAndColums to Table and Colums
            --Select Table
            DECLARE @Table VARCHAR(25)
            SET  @Table = SUBSTRING(@TableAndColums,0,CHARINDEX(':',@TableAndColums))
            SET @TableAndColums = REPLACE(@TableAndColums,@Table + ':' , '')
            --Split to Colums
            WHILE LEN(@TableAndColums) > 0
             BEGIN
                DECLARE @Column VARCHAR(25)
                IF CHARINDEX('.',@TableAndColums) > 0
                    SET  @Column = SUBSTRING(@TableAndColums,0,CHARINDEX('.',@TableAndColums))
                ELSE
                    BEGIN
                    SET  @Column = @TableAndColums
                    SET @TableAndColums = ''
                    END

                    BEGIN
                --insert result in to #Results table
                INSERT INTO #Results
                EXEC
                    (
                        'SELECT ' + @Table + '.Id AS ''TargetId'', '''+@Table+''' AS ''DBName''
                        FROM ' + @Table +
                        ' WHERE  ' + @Column + ' LIKE N''%' + @Key + '%'''
                    )
                END

             SET @TableAndColums = REPLACE(@TableAndColums,@Column + '.' , '')
            END
         END
     SET @SearchKeys = REPLACE(@SearchKeys,@Key + ',' , '')
    END
    --return found values
    SELECT DISTINCT TargetId , DBname FROM #Results
END
```

For some reason it searches only for the first key ignoring all the rest keys. I can not find out why this is happening. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

The very first thing I'll warn you about here is your procedure is wide open to injection attack. Injection attack is in and of itself a broad topic. If you're interested, I suggest reading this article. If you do absolutely need this type of interface (i.e. you can't use static typed SQL or something like Entity Framework to take care of the queries for you), you must must MUST make sure that any strings being executed at run time (e.g. @column, @table, @key) are parametrized or bracketed. This procedure, as written, will also fail when an inputted table does not contain an ID column or when an inputted column doesn't exist.

http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

In terms of how you're doing string splitting, I'd look at the article below. While there's no way to eliminate the need to loop over each table, by putting all your search strings into a table using a string splinting function like the ones mentioned in this article, you can search all search conditions on a single table at once. Something like this:

```
select *
from #SearchConditions a
inner join dbo.TargetTable b
    on b.Name like '%' + a.SearchKey + '%'
```

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/